# Which regression model(s) should be the most appropriate with this usual scatter plot but unusual distribution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression, data-science, curve

I need to fit two different regression models to the following `df` (e.g. curves belonging to two different families).

Thus, thinking about the type of regression that I know, there are :

- Linear regression (the green one in the pic below, just to show)
- Polynomial regression
- Ridge regression
- Lasso regression
- ElasticNet regression

The `df` is super-simple, just two columns `x`and `y` with 450 entries each.

The scatter plot is the following:

[image]

BUT, when I go through the train/test plotting process I get the following one :

[image]

Now, it is clear that a simple linear model can't be enough with a train/test distribution like this.

BUT, when I move to investigate the MSE (mean squared error) I get something interesting :

```
Train Error: 0.06336815111266955
Test Error: 0.06359148208824823
```

I am sure about the code (that I not reported). I checked it with another toy dataset and worked perfectly.

May someone help me, please?

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: in the model fitting process I applied `MinMaxScaler()` in range `[0,1]` function

Comment: hi @Aneema, did you normalize you y values? How is it that your predicted and observed values look different from the first plot

Comment: @StupidWolf, sorry I forget to mention that I applied MinMaxScaler() function to the target variable y

Comment: yeah you should not do that. redo the fit with a ridge / polynomial or even linear regression. you should get something that goes closer.

Comment: @StupidWolf just tryed it. The train/test graph does not change. The MSE is now:
Train Error: 8465.365206208307
Test Error: 8495.200040220916

Comment: @StupidWolf give me a minute. I update the post with the whole code.

Comment: wait wait.. sorry I just realized,you have only 1 dependent variable, it's pointless to use lasso, ridge elastic net. A polynomial should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212509/discussion-between-aneema-and-stupidwolf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very sure where it went wrong, might be a combination of split for train / test or fitting it wrongly, below I simulate some data that looks like yours, and you can see it works:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

LR = linear_model.LinearRegression()

x = np.linspace(7, 15, num=100)
y = x + 2*x**2 + np.random.normal(0,5,size=100)
poly = PolynomialFeatures(2)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3)

clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(poly.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(-1,1)), y_train)
pred_train = clf.predict(poly.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(-1,1)))
pred_test = clf.predict(poly.fit_transform(X_test.reshape(-1,1)))
```

We can plot the results for train:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':X_train,'y':y_train,'pred':pred_train})
sns.scatterplot(x='x',y='y',data=df)
sns.lineplot(x='x',y='pred',data=df,color="orange")
```

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':X_test,'y':y_test,'pred':pred_test})
sns.scatterplot(x='x',y='y',data=df)
sns.lineplot(x='x',y='pred',data=df,color="orange")
```

[image]